# jQuery, get the original height of a div

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, height, mouseover

I have some div .frame with a height of 200px.
When the mouse is over one of these div, with the jQuery function animate(), I'm setting the height of this div to 300px, and when the mouse leaves this div, I'm re-setting its height to 200px.

The script is pretty basic:

```
$(document).on('mouseenter mouseleave', '.frame', function( e ) {
    var el=$(this);
    if(e.type == "mouseenter"){
        el.stop(true,true).animate({'height':300});
    }else{
        el.stop(true,true).animate({'height':200});
    }  
});
```

My issue is: from the begining I know that the height of .frame is 200px, but what if I don't know this value? how can set .frame in its original height in the seconde animate()?

Comment: Will you be doing this for more than one element? It changes the answer slightly.

Comment: yes exactly, for more than one element, I'm editing my post

Comment: You can only have one element with that ID, so the code implies that there will only be one element.

Comment: How do you insert the element into the DOM? You have to add an attribute to the elements when they are inserted to be able to get the original height

Comment: @adeneo CSS might be controlling the height. What attribute will need adding?

Comment: Actually @adeneo's reasoning is sensible now he/she's explained it - the data needs storing when the element is created because mouseenter keeps triggering every time the mouse moves, so to avoid several extra lines of code it would be better to store the height when the element is created.

Comment: No, scrap that, it can be stored once on first mouseenter.

Comment: @Popnoodles - It would work with storing the data on first mouseenter, but it's more reliable and easier to just store it when the elements are inserted, like this -> **http://jsfiddle.net/FZXt9/7/**

Comment: @adeneo I know what you're saying and it makes sense but there are a couple of issues: the frame may change size when its contents load or change (we don't know that), it's better to write contextually - there's no need to add data to the page until the user needs or is about to need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working example http://jsfiddle.net/FZXt9/8/

Save the height as data on each element. Because you're using .on() to select elements that may be created after this code is run, this suggests you're creating the `.frame` elements dynamically, so setting a variable on page load will not work. This will also work for multiple elements.

```
$(document).on('mouseenter mouseleave', '.frame', function( e ) {
    var el=$(this);
    if(e.type == "mouseenter"){
        if (!el.data('originalheight')) el.data('originalheight', el.height()); // set the data
        el.stop().animate({height:300});
    }else{
        el.stop().animate({height:el.data('originalheight')});
    }  
});
```

Please note, I have changed #frame to .frame, using a class rather than an ID because IDs must be unique and you have said you need it to work for multiple elements.

Comment: I was about the post the same, but without a way to set the data attribute on the elements, it's pretty useless.

Comment: @adeneo Data is only an attribute before the DOM is ready. After that it's stored in an object. What do you mean "without a way to set the data"?

Comment: How data is stored isn't the problem, storing data related to elements that aren't there is.

Comment: Data is stored on mouseenter. The element exists. Have you mixed up my answer with one of the two others that don't account for that?

Comment: thanks @Popnoodles I made a jsFiddle and it doesn't seem to work: http://jsfiddle.net/malamine_kebe/FZXt9/2/ when the mouse leavs the div, it is also changing originalheight no?

Comment: Exactly, everytime the mouse enters, the data is updated, so the next time it will be 300, and this will never work. You have to store the height in data once, and only once, and that is usually done on first page load, but here the elements doesn't exists on pageload, so the data must be stored when the element is inserted into the DOM.

Comment: @adeneo no it just needs storing on first mouseenter

Comment: thanks a lot @Popnoodles and happy new year to you all

Answer (score 0):

May be you can cache your div's height first then use it in the `mouseleave`:

```
var eleheight = $('#frame').height();

$(document).on('mouseenter mouseleave', '#frame', function( e ) {
    var el=$(this);
    if(e.type == "mouseenter"){
        el.stop(true,true).animate({'height':300});
    }else{
        el.stop(true,true).animate({'height': eleheight });
    }  
});
```

Comment: I thought of it but actualy I'll need the script on a random number of div, not just on one, so I don't know if set a variable for each single div is a good solution

Comment: There may be an issue with this. OP is using .on() like  .live() so that frame may not exist when your code is run

Answer (score 0):

An interesting way to solve this is to store arbitrary [data](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/) as the object with 'mouseenter' and 'mouseleave' properties:

```
$( '.frame' ).each( function() {
    $(this).data( 'height', { 'mouseenter': 300, 'mouseleave': $(this).height() } );
});
```

, and then just use the name of the event:

```
$(document).on('mouseenter mouseleave', '.frame', function( e ) {
    $(this) .stop(true,true)
            .animate( { height: $(this).data( 'height' )[ e.type ] } );
});
```